# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #2](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/election/2) on Computational Science — your first "full" election — has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators are... the faces you already know, your previous pro-tem mods!

[image: Anton Menshov]

[image: nicoguaro]

[image: Paul]

Please thank them for volunteering to walk this community through its beta phase, and for stepping up and nominating in the election too!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/election/2) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5854372492738560).

Comment: Long live the SciComp Moderation Team!  You make us proud.