# 2022 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #3](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/election/3) on Computational Science has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: hardmath]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly – please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking the following user, who will be stepping down as moderator:

[image: Paul]

Paul has been a moderator since being appointed as a pro-tem mod in 2012 (shortly after the site went into beta), and was [reelected last year after the site left beta](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/q/615/40128) – thanks to them for the decade they spent helping improve the site!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/election/3) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5714481270226944).

Answer (score 7):

@Paul, You've been an essential member of the Computational Science SE moderators team! You were definitely the one who essentially helped to shape this community to where it is now.

It was a pleasure to serve here with you, and I hope you will still contribute to our community as a valued member.

@hardmath, welcome to the team! I hope you'll enjoy this experience as I am truly confident that our community is one of the best in the whole Stack Exchange.